# How to compare multidimensional array by columns

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am creating a function to compare items in a multidimensional array of length 6. I compare from bottom to top and left to right. If the first elements (index 0)  are as follows `i[0][5] > i[0][4] > i[0][3] > i[0][2] > i[0][1] > i[0][0]` it returns false and if there is only at least one element that does not respect the rule above it should return false.

When I try to use for loop, the program only returns 1 result not all expected ones.

```
let multidimArr = [
[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1]
[2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4]
[6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 5]
[4, 7, 6, 8, 7, 6]
[4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9]
];

function compare() {

for (var i=0, len=multidimArr.length; i<len; i++) {

    for (var j=0, len2=multidimArr[i].length; j<len2; j++) {
      if( i <= 0 ) continue;

        if ( multidimArr[i][j] < multidimArr[i - 1][j] ) {
          return false
           );


      } else if( multidimArr[i][j] > multidimArr[i - 1][j] ){
         return true; 

      }
}

console.log('the status is [' + compare() + ']');
```

For this code the **expected result is false for the first column, true for the second, false for the 3rd, true for 4th, false for 5th and true for last column**.

Unfortunately it only return false.

Comment: Since your function only returns once, it will never return more than one value. If you want multiple values, create an array, add elements according to whatever scheme you want, then return the array...

Comment: Right....as soon as you do a return `compare()` is done, all loops get exited  and will log that one result only

Comment: I don't understand your expected results... Could you elaborate?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. What I want is to compare this array by column and return true if items in previous columns are smaller and false if only one fails to this rule.
First column items: 1, 2, 5, 6, 4, 4 should return false.
2nd column items: 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9 should return true
And so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array and take `true` for the first row and then check the last and actual value and respect the last check.

```js
function check(array) {
    return array.reduce((r, a, i, { [i - 1]: b }) => a.map((v, j) => i
            ? r[j] && b[j] < v
            : true
    ), []);
}


var array = [[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1], [2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2], [5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4], [6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 5], [4, 7, 6, 8, 7, 6], [4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 9]];

console.log(check(array));
```